# How to make sure that I always get the message of an exception in Python in a safe way?

Tags: python

In Java, getting the message of an exception is as easy as always calling a certain method.
But in Python, it seems to be impossible. Sometimes it works by doing this:

```
try:
    # Code
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
```

But sometimes capturing an exception like that ends up by raising another exception because the message attribute doesn't exist. Ironically sad. Trying to control a error produces another one...

Sometimes it works by doing this:

```
print(e.msg)
```

But sometimes it also raises missing attribute exception.

Sometimes this works as well:

```
print(str(e))
```

But sometimes it prints an empty string so it is simply useless.

I've even heard that it depends on the library you're using, on the concrete Exception implementation. That seems really stupid for me. How can I handle an error for printing what has happened if I never know what attributes does it have for retrieving the error message?

Comment: I suppose one solution is to catch a specific exception rather than the generic superclass

Comment: Catch each specific exception type and handle each one appropriately as James suggests

Comment: See the `traceback` module. If your goal is to log "errors I did not expect to get at all", then the traceback is going to be 100x more useful than some random string that says "an operation failed" (or, as you say, an empty string if the module writer failed to add a message). If it is an error that you had some expectation of receiving, then as others have said, you should be catching that specific exception, not the base class `Exception`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But sometimes it prints an empty string so it is simply useless.

Yeah, that's what happens when someone raises an exception without a message. Blame authors (of the lib you are using) for that.

Generally you can use `repr` which is supposed to be unambiguous and if not overriden contains at least information about the exception's type:

```
try:
    0/0
except Exception as exc:
    print(repr(exc))
    raise
```

If you need whole traceback you can use

```
import traceback
try:
    0/0
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    raise
```